# Only works when type of variable is derived class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        object objTest = test;

        Console.WriteLine(test.GetType());    // Output: "OperatorOverload.Test"
        Console.WriteLine(objTest.GetType()); // Output: "OperatorOverload.Test"

        Console.WriteLine(test == null);    // Output: "True"
        Console.WriteLine(objTest == null); // Output: "False"

        test.Equals(null);    // Output: "Hi!"
        objTest.Equals(null); // Output: "Hi!"

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Test looks like this:

```
class Test
{

    public static bool operator ==(Test obj1, Test obj2)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Test obj1, Test obj2)
    {
        return !(obj1 == obj2);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
        return true;
    }

}
```

It appears that operator overloading only works when the type of the variable you're dealing with is the class the operator overload is defined in. I can see why that would be the case, as I'm looking for a safe way of checking whether an object equals null.

My questions are:

Do overloaded operators only work if the type of the variable is the class the operator is defined in (my code tells me yes, but I could be making a mistake)?

Is the following code a safe way of checking whether an object equals null?

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass(); // may have overloaded operators
if ((object)obj == null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Check out the answer here, I think it's relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2186908/453056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# <strike>overriding</strike> overloading an operator essentially creates a static method with its name like op_xxx(e.g. op_Add, op_Equality). In your question, `test == null` behaviors like `Test.op_Equality(test, null)` which returns `true` obviously. While `objTest == null` calls `Object.op_Equality(test, null)` that returns false. On the other hand, you override the virtual method `Equals`, so `test.Equals` and `objTest.Equals` have the same result.

Comment: Thanks, now that I think of operators as static methods, it makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: @haiyyu: That's why we require you to declare the operator *as a static method*.

Comment: Actually, the method `object.op_Equality()` does not exist. But the behavior is similar as if it did.

Comment: The all-too-subtle terminolology difference is that operators are *overloaded*, not overridden.

Answer (score 5):

> Is the following code a safe way of checking whether an object equals null?

```
if ((object)obj == null)
```

Yes. However, I personally prefer:

```
if (object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
```

because now it is *crystal clear* to the reader of the code precisely what is going on here.

You might be interested to read my article about the design factors that make `Equals` and `operator==` such odd ducks:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun.aspx